# disabled select field importing to mysql

Tags: javascript, html, mysql

I have a script where I am trying to only import fields that are not disabled to mysql.
my problem is that when its disabled it still imports the field that is in the selection

```js
function toggleCatDisability()
  {
   document.getElementsByClassName('cat_border')[0].disabled = false;
   document.getElementsByClassName('tech_border')[0].disabled = true;
   document.getElementsByClassName('splatter_border')[0].disabled = true;
   document.getElementsByClassName('fancy_border')[0].disabled = true;
   
  }
  function toggleTechDisability()
  {
   document.getElementsByClassName('tech_border')[0].disabled = false;
   document.getElementsByClassName('cat_border')[0].disabled = true;
   document.getElementsByClassName('splatter_border')[0].disabled = true;
   document.getElementsByClassName('fancy_border')[0].disabled = true;
  }
```

```html
<center>
<input type="button" value="Update Tag" onClick="updateTagSettings()" />
</center><br /><br /><div id="ajax_spot" style="text-align:center;"></div>
<center><input type="text" id="tag_name" value="" maxlength="15"/>
<div>
</div>
<div>
Border Style:
<div>
<input type="button" value="Kitten"onclick="toggleCatDisability()"/>
</select>
 Color:<select id="tag_border" class="cat_border" disabled="disabled">
  <option value="Border_Cat_Black.png">Black</option>
  <option value="Border_Cat_DBlue.png">Dark Blue</option>
  <option value="Border_Cat_LBlue.png">Light Blue</option>
  <option value="Border_Cat_Green.png">Green</option>
  <option value="Border_Cat_Orange.png">Orange</option>
  <option value="Border_Cat_Pink.png">Pink</option>
  <option value="Border_Cat_Purple.png">Purple</option>
  <option value="Border_Cat_Red.png">Red</option>
  <option value="Border_Cat_Yellow.png">Yellow</option>
  
</select> 
</div>
</div>
<div>
<input type="button" value="Tech"onclick="toggleTechDisability()"/>
Color:<select id="tag_border" class="tech_border" disabled="disabled">
  <option value="Border_Cat_Black.png">Black</option>
  <option value="Border_Cat_DBlue.png">Dark Blue</option>
  <option value="Border_Cat_LBlue.png">Light Blue</option>
  <option value="Border_Cat_Green.png">Green</option>
  <option value="Border_Cat_Orange.png">Orange</option>
  <option value="Border_Cat_Pink.png">Pink</option>
  <option value="Border_Cat_Purple.png">Purple</option>
  <option value="Border_Cat_Red.png">Red</option>
  <option value="Border_Cat_Yellow.png">Yellow</option>
</select> 
</div>
<div>
   Background:<select id="tag_bg" >      
  <option>Choose Color</option>
  <option value="BG_Black.png">Black</option>
  <option value="BG_DBlue.png">Dark Blue</option>
  <option value="BG_LBlue.png">Light Blue</option>
  <option value="BG_Green.png">Green</option>
  <option value="BG_Orange.png">Orange</option>
  <option value="BG_Pink.png">Pink</option>
  <option value="BG_Purple.png">Purple</option>
  <option value="BG_Red.png">Red</option>
  <option value="BG_Yellow.png">Yellow</option>
  
</select> 
</div>
<div>
</div>
</center>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

> **Edit:** PHP and Javascript-

**PHP**

```
function updateTagValues() {
global $logon;
$tag_name= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tagname']);
$tag_bg= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tagbg']);
$tag_border= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tagborder']);
$tag_decal= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tagdecal']);  
mysql_query("UPDATE gamezove_deciet.groups SET leader_name = '" . $logon->username . "', name='" . $tag_name . "', bg='" . $tag_bg . "', border='" . $tag_border . "', decal='" . $tag_decal . "' WHERE `leader_name`='" . $logon->username . "'", $this->c) or die("Something went wrong, please try again!");
    if (strlen($password) > 0){
    echo "Your tag have been updated!"; 
    if(strlen($password) > 0){
        $logon->logout();
    }       
    }
}
```

**Javascript/jQuery**

```
function saveTagSettings() {
  var tagname = $("#tag_name").val()
  var tagbg = $("#tag_bg").val()
  var tagborder = $("#tag_border").val()
  var tagdecal = $("#tag_decal").val()
  $("#ajax_spot").html("<img src='theme/" + theme + "/images/ajax.gif' />")
  $.post("inc/forum_ajax.php", { ajax: 19, tagname: tagname, tagbg: tagbg, tagborder: tagborder, tagdecal: tagdecal}, function(data) {
  $("#ajax_spot").html(data)
  });  
}
```

I know that there is a way to do this I just don't know how.
I'm guessing I need to do more with the disable function but not exactly sure what.
any help would be greatly appreciated:)

Comment: How are you submitting the form data? For this I would use javascript (client-side validation) allowing you to check if an element is disabled, then use ajax to post that data to your php file but also still validate the data server-side. Client-side can be edited/change by the client so when sending anything over to the server it's important to use validation.

Comment: I am submitting the data from php and js. How would I go about what you are saying? I don't know any ajax really is there a way I can do this strictly with php html and js?

Comment: I think it would be a good idea for you to display the javascript that posts that data. Relevant information is the key to getting correct answers. (And a detailed description of what you wish to achieve and error reporting)

Comment: ok one moment let me get it

Comment: Look near the bottom of your question, you should see an edit option.

Comment: all you need to do is add an if condition to your `saveTagSettings()` function to see which of the two select elements are disabled. the one that isn't you want to place into the call and leave the other one out.

Comment: could you show me an example possibly?